# Issue with routerLink directive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm writing an Angular2 app that includes some routing with the component router.

As of today, I'm using angular-2.0.0-beta.3.

while in a child component, I try to use the `routerlink` directive with the following template:

`<a [routerLink]=['/Home']>Go Home</a>`.

Instead, what's getting rendered is:

`<a>Go Home</a>`

with no exception thrown whatsoever, leaving it as an invalid anchor.

It's important to note that `router.navigate(['Home'])` is working as expected.

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [WrapperService],
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
   @RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home', as: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

home.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: '<a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Go home</a>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

Actually, these files should only show a working link to...the current page (for simplicity).

What is missing here?

Comment: I thought of publishing a Plunkr, but I cannot reproduce it there.
Nevertheless, I can't notice anything I've done differently between the Plunkr and my App.

Comment: try reverting back to beta.2

Comment: No, It's not a matter of the version. Tried that already with beta.0-3

Comment: We are going to need more code to be able to find the problem.

Comment: You are not supposed to write the URL but the "name" of the route definition, I'm guessing yours is "Home", try this: `<a [routerLink]=['Home']>Go Home</a>` and make sure the anchor is in a component or in a child of a component that has the route definition for `Home`

Comment: I use the name of the route. Your proposal behaves the same (although I think I need the `/` to represent the parent component).

Comment: Added the 2 components code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that I was missing the **angular2-polyfills.js** dependency.
I'm not sure why it is needed, but apparently, it affects several things, among them is the way links are rendered.

Answer (score 2):

The `as` syntax you are using was deprecated a while back and renamed to `name`

Here is how I define my routes.

```
 @RouteConfig([
   new Route({ path: '/spreadsheet', component: Spreadsheet, name: 'Spreadsheet' })
 ])

<a [routerLink]="['/Spreadsheet']">Virtualized Spreadsheet</a>
```

More info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Comment: That maybe right, but it's not what solves my issue here. The example I published do work in Plunkr, but apparently, my application setup prevents from the link to show well. I need to find out why.