# Angular2: routeLink does not create href attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have three very basic components: `AppComponent`, `AdminComponent` and `LoginComponent`. Both `AppComponent` and `LoginComponent` show a link to `AdminComponent`. `AppComponent` contains the `router-outlet` and all the routing configuration.

Now for some reason angular renders `<a [routerLink]="['Admin']">Admin</a>` to `<a href="/admin">Admin</a>` in `AppComponent` just as expected. However, the exact same link in `LoginComponent` is rendered to `<a>Admin</a>`. What am I doing wrong?

Angular versions tried: 2.0.0-beta.8 and 2.0.0-beta.9.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {AdminComponent} from './admin.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ww-app',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['Admin']">Admin</a>             // This link works as expected

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, name: 'Login', useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/admin', component: AdminComponent, name: 'Admin' }
])
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'ww-login',
  directives: [RouterLink],
  template: `
    <div>
      <a [routerLink]="['Admin']">Admin</a>        // Renders <a>Admin</a>
      <div>login box </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class LoginComponent {
}
```

**Rendered HTML output**

```
<ww-app>
  <a href="/admin">Admin</a>          <!-- link as expected (AppComponent)-->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <ww-login _ngcontent-nky-2="">
    <div>
      <a>Admin</a>                    <!-- href is missing here (LoginComponent)-->
      <div>login box </div>
    </div>
  </ww-login>
</ww-app>
```

---

**Update**

Alright, I just stumpled upon a similar question on so [Issue with routerLink directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234027/issue-with-routerlink-directive?rq=1). Looks like angular2-polyfill.js is the bad boy. See [Thierry's modified plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4yCQydWqJ4FfPRmVcp5G?p=preview) where I removed the polyfill from index.html.

**Follow up question**:

[angular2-polyfill](https://github.com/samverschueren/angular2-polyfill) declares itself as

> Angular2 polyfill for Angular1

It might be stupid to ask, but do I really need it? Obviously it fixed a problem for me, but it gives me kind of a bad feeling as this is not Angular 1. The additional deprecation warnings don't help either...

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: Sounds similar to this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6358 , but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier: I'm currently using 2.0.0-beta.9. Happened in beta 8 too.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem without success in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/I3XaEcXfJLfOi1Zws1Rk?p=preview. Could you provide a plunkr reproducing the problem? Thanks!

Comment: It is not necessary Angel !

Comment: @ThierryTemplier: Strangely I cannot reproduce this issue on plunker....

Comment: @Roman could you provide the js files you included and your systemjs configuration from your HTML entry file? Thanks!

Comment: Roman, it works in our case ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, very appreciated! It looks like angular2-polyfill causes the problem... respectively the lack of it. See updated question.

Comment: did you try 
<a [routerLink]="['/Admin']">Admin</a>  "adding the slash " ?

Comment: @εEridani yep, I tried that already. Didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are setting your directives as `[RouterLink]` instead of `[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`.

If you see the code, the RouterLink directive is for other tags different than `<a>`. The router link directive that works with `<a>` tags is the RouterLinkWithHref.

Take a look at the code in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts

```js
@Directive({selector: ':not(a)[routerLink]'})
export class RouterLink { ... }

@Directive({selector: 'a[routerLink]'})
export class RouterLinkWithHref implements OnChanges, OnDestroy { ... }
```